# Chrome extension rejection for narrow and unclear purpose

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

When submitting updates for our extension, we receive the following message with rejection from the Chrome store:

"To have your item reinstated, please ensure:

The purpose of the extension is clear to users; and
The extension either limits its functionality to a narrow focus area of subject matter or to a narrow browser function.
To serve multiple purposes with your extensions, please package each purpose as a separate extension."

Does anyone know the criteria used when determining if the purpose is clear or if the extension is trying to do too much? Our extension is used to demonstrate metrics more conveniently that our clients would normally go to our webpage to see, so it shows a few different but very related items (all of which fit the central theme of showing connected metrics).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Chrome Extension Quality Guideline](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#chrome_apps):

**Extensions Quality Guidelines**

> An extension must have a single purpose that is narrow and
>   easy-to-understand. Do not create an extension that requires users to
>   accept bundles of unrelated functionality, such as an email notifier
>   and a news headline aggregator, or downloads a local executable. If
>   two pieces of functionality are clearly separate, they should be put
>   into two different extensions, and users should have the ability to
>   install and uninstall them separately. For example, functionality that
>   displays product ratings and reviews, but also injects ads into web
>   pages, should not be bundled into a single extension. Similarly,
>   toolbars that provide a broad array of functionality or entry points
>   into services are better delivered as separate extensions, so that
>   users can select the services they want.

This is further explained in the [FAQS page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose) answering these questions:

1. Why did Google launch a “single purpose” Chrome extensions policy?
2. Where can I find the “single purpose” policy?
3. What does “single purpose” actually mean?